# How to detect if the first non-space/non-tab character in a string is '-' (minus)?

Tags: macros

I have a macro `\myNumericString` that expands to a string of numbers, with the possibility to present a minus sign as a first non-space character.
How can I construct a macro:

```
\isNegative{\myNumericString}{ true }{ false }
```

in order to make decisions on how to treat `\myNumericString` in successive typesetting steps?
Here's a simple case of usage:

```
\[
   4 \times \isNegative{\myNumericString}{
       ( \myNumericString ) }{ \myNumericString }
\]
```

Comment: `\ifnum\myNumericString<0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are *sure* that `\myNumericString` is what TeX expects as a `<number>`, then

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\isNegative}[1]{%
  \ifnum#1<0
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi}
\makeatother
```

If `\myNumericString` possibly has a decimal part, you can use

```
\ifdim#1pt<0pt
```

instead (the integer part cannot exceed 16383).

A better definition that only examines the first token in the expansion of `\myNumericString` is

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\isNegative}{m}
  {
   \exp_args:Nx \str_if_eq:nnTF { \tl_head:f { #1 } } { - }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Here's an example document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\isNegative}{m}
  {
   \exp_args:Nx \str_if_eq:nnTF { \tl_head:f { #1 } } { - }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\def\myNumericString{123.456}
$4\times\isNegative{\myNumericString}{(\myNumericString)}{\myNumericString}$

\def\myNumericString{-123.456}
$4\times\isNegative{\myNumericString}{(\myNumericString)}{\myNumericString}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

if you need it for all arguments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\isNegative[1]{\expandafter\is@Negative#1\@nil}
\def\is@Negative{\@ifnextchar-{\@negative}{\@positive}}
\def\@negative-#1\@nil{#1 starts with a minus}
\def\@positive#1\@nil{#1 starts not with a minus}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\def\myNumericString{123.456}
\isNegative{\myNumericString}

\def\myNumericString{-123.456}
\isNegative{\myNumericString}

\isNegative{     -foo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 This is a nice solution as well, but here \isNegative doesn't fit with the macro proposed in the answer.